# VSCode App Service Deploy Failed 2gb zip file limit

Tags: azure-web-app-service, web-deployment

Deploying Flask app using VSCode App Service fails.  The zip file is 2.2 gb - too large.

What procedure can I use to deploy large projects?
Can I upload the project in 2 or more steps ?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-zip

Created new web app "mysite": https://mysite.azurewebsites.net
mysite: Starting deployment...
mysite: Creating zip package...
mysite: Zip package size: 2.22 GB
mysite: Fetching changes.
mysite: Cleaning up temp folders from previous zip deployments and extracting pushed zip file /tmp/zipdeploy/b02a0e95-4e86-4bcc-a71f-9997355a55fb.zip (54.56 MB) to /tmp/zipdeploy/extracted
mysite: Offset to Central Directory cannot be held in an Int64.
mysite: Deployment failed.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in your post [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/474150/index.html) "The zip file limit of 2048MB (2GB) can't be increased in App service. This is by the design and is not a limitation of Kudu but of IIS since the request goes through the Frontends. When the integrated pipeline is used, we go through webengine code (webengine4!MgdGetRequestBasics) which doesn't support more than 2 GB content-length."